# How to conver daily data over the period of 30 years to Monthly data for a multivariate series?

Tags: r, dplyr, xts, lubridate

I have data frame as shown below:

```
 str(Rainfall_Complete)
'data.frame':   8221 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ Date          : Date, format: "1985-04-29" "1985-04-30" "1985-05-01" ...
 $ Month         : Ord.factor w/ 12 levels "Jan"<"Feb"<"Mar"<..:
 $ Season        : Factor w/ 4 levels "Monsoon","PostMonsoon",..:.
 $ Year          : chr  "1985" "1985" "1985" "1985" ...
 $ Stn A         : num  0 8.8 0 15 26.2 0 2.5 0 0 0 ...
 $ Stn B         : num  0 0 26 11 13.8 20 0.26 0 0 0 ...
 $ Stn C         : num  0.1 0 0 0 13.5 27 16 5 0 0 …
```

I want to convert the above daily time series to monthly time series
I want my data to look something like this

```
Year  Month StnA   StnB   StnC……..

1985   Jan   150    100   120

1985   Feb   120     98    58

….

2010   Jan   200    100    87

2010   Feb   140    145    120
```

I tried the following, however it works only for univariate series

```
library(dplyr)
Monthly_rainfall <- Rainfall_Complete %>% group_by(Year,Month)%>% summarise()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you need to convert year and month into proper date format 1st,later use your code you will be able to convert it

Comment: If you want to use `summarise` on multiple columns try `summarise_at`. You'll be able to get the `sum` of multiple columns at the same time, based on your grouping.

Comment: Maybe `padr::thicken()` could be of help.

Comment: Please take a look at how to make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it easier to help

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt uses `dplyr`, but the question is tagged with `xts` and `lubridate`, thus here is a solution using those packages with a reprex.

```
library(lubridate)
library(xts)

## Create some basic data
ans6 <- xts(anscombe[, 1:6], order.by = as.Date("2018-01-28") + 1:nrow(anscombe))

## Summary by month
mon6 <- apply.monthly(ans6, FUN = mean)

## Re-format
df6 <- as.data.frame(mon6)
df6$year <- year(rownames(df6))
df6$month <- month(rownames(df6), label = TRUE)

df6
## x1       x2       x3    x4       y1       y2 year month
## 2018-01-31 10.33333 10.33333 10.33333 8.000 7.523333 8.673333 2018   Jan
## 2018-02-08  8.50000  8.50000  8.50000 9.375 7.492500 7.061250 2018   Feb
```